# Table Design for Multiple Option Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to determine if this table structure is optimal for what i'm trying to achieve. Here is the current structure:

[image]

The option data table would have a many to 1 relationship with the option_field. Basically i'm trying to create a generic option system where you can create fields - the option data table relates the specific system entity (customer, user, package, service, customer package, customer service) using the corresponding fields. Customer Packages and Customer Services option data is defined when the customerid, customeraccountid and customeraccountpersonid have values as well as the packageid or serviceid.

the question i'm wondering is if it makes sense to have all those ID columns on the option_data record, or if it would make more sense to segment those out somehow. Ideally this option service would be generic enough that if i wanted to add more entity type options i would just have to add the corresponding ID field in the option_data table down the road. My only concern with this is that a good chunk of those id's will be null since not all option_data will ALWAYS use ALL the id fields in the option_data table.

hope this makes sense... not sure if this is the ideal table design for what i'm trying to acheive - please let me know if i can further clarify.

Comment: So you're basically implementing an elaborate version of an Entity-Attribute-Value table? The Entity is the combination of the customer/account/package/service. The Attribute is the OptionFieldId. The Value is called `Data` in your table.

Comment: You can do this, but it won't be _optimal_. EAV is never optimal, it's always wasteful. You are increasing flexibility, but you are decreasing optimization. This is a tradeoff you have to make a decision about. But don't think of it as optimal.

Comment: ok i see - just curious - what would be considered an "optimal" structure in comparison? I think thats what i'm just trying to wrap my head around is what other options i have from a design perspective.

Comment: Optimal is to use normal columns, one column per option. So you can use data types properly, you can use NOT NULL for required options, you can use constraints, and create indexes. But this is not as flexible, because you need to know what options exist before creating the columns.

Comment: EAV, and your options management thing you describe above, are examples of the [Inner-Platform Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect), or designing a system that is so customizable that it becomes a replica of the software system you're already using. It's obviously possible to do this but it's _a lot_ of work. You are already using a database that supports columns as metadata and rows as data. Use that. Your options system is seeking to create a new system of metadata and data on top of what the database already provides.